# EclipseLink JPA many to many with extra column getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have 3 tables: USER(id, name), AD(id, title) and USER_AD(user_id, ad_id, status). All I want is to save USER_AD when saving a new AD.

user.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserAd> userAds;
```

ad.java:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "ad", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserAd> userAds;
```

UserAd.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_ad")
@NamedQuery(name="UserAd.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM UserAd u")
@IdClass(UserAdID.class)
public class UserAd implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Integer userId;

    @Id
    private Integer adId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="AD_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private Ad ad;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private User user;
}
```

UserAdID.java:

```
public class UserAdID implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private Integer userId;
    @JoinColumn(name="AD_ID")
    private Integer adId;
}
```

when i do a `adRepository.saveAndFlush(ad);` i am keep getting: "`Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ADID' in 'field list'`". I printed out the sql, it is "

```
INSERT INTO user_ad (ADID, USERID, ASK_CONTACT, `ORDER`, STATUS, TYPE, AD_ID, USER_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [null, null, 0, 0, , seller, 14, 2]
```

". Where are ADID and USERID come from? Did I define AD_ID and USER_ID wrong? Please help.

Comment: You should put the Column names on the fields "adId" and "userId" in the "UserAd" class (as @Column, not @JoinColumn) ... and NOT in its IdClass

Comment: You will want to look into JPA 2.1's derived IDs, as your current setup has 2 mappings for the AD_ID and USER_ID fields.  Either that, or make one insertable=false,updateable=false so that JPA knows which one controls the field.